# Open source libraries/frameworks in SaaS Product

Tags: open-source, licensing, saas

My company is offering a SaaS solution which is accessible via a web browser. We are using external libraries/frameworks like jQuery or the Zend framework in our solution. Do we have to make the different licenses from this libraries/frameworks accessible to our customers, for legal reasons? Do we have to mention the external libraries/frameworks on a credits page, or is it legal just to provide our service without giving credits to other libraries/frameworks?
Can we still provide our service under our proprietary license (don't know if it makes sense)?

Or software is not downloadable, but we are shipping whole appliances or virtualmachines with our solution.

Comment: Software as a Service http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each license will have its own requirements, but most permissive licenses (such as the [MIT](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) and [Apache](http://www.apache.org/licenses/) licenses) don't require you to specifically mention them or their license to your application users. Instead they require that you maintain distribute the license and copyright information if you distribute the source code. In addition, the Apache license in particular requires that you provide a notice in any source file that has been modified stating such.

I have seen library [licenses](http://eej.dk/angryant/wp-content/themes/angryant/download.php?p=Path2&f=Package) (see the second requirement), however, which specifically require attribution within a linking application.

I am not a lawyer, and you should consult with a lawyer if you have doubts concerning licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Often frameworks have this kind of information on their website. If not, check the wording of the license itself and its website. Different licenses have different requirements. Copies of the GPL and LGPL, for example, should be distributed with the source code they cover.

As for providing your product under a proprietary license, again, it depends on the license. If you were to make use of a 3rd party library as a part of your product, and that library was covered by the GPL, your product must also be distributed under the GPL. However, if it was covered by the LGPL you would not have that restriction and you could license your product how you please.

Look here for jQuery: http://jquery.org/license/. I think you will want the MIT license (although I am not familiar with the details, I think it will suit you better than the GPL).

Comment: My main concern is not our license, but do we have to list the external libraries/frameworks and their licenses in our solution (for example on a credits page in the about navigation)?